# Getting error ORA-06502 while creating Dynamic SQL query using procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have created a procedure and it requires Dynamic SQL block.

Procedure is as below which complies correctly but when I try to run it , it gives the below error.

I have tried to use cast() for all the variable which are used here. But this does not help.

Also, I am trying to run this procedure on Oracle using SQL - Developer tool.

Once the dynamic SQL is stored in sqlquery variable I would try and run the dynamic query and display its results!

```
**Output**
*Connecting to the database XXX.
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at "XXX.PROCEDURE2", line 28
ORA-06512: at line 6
Who are you ? 
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database XXX.*
```

**Procedure**

```
*create or replace PROCEDURE PROCEDURE2 (var_owner IN dba_tab_cols.owner%TYPE) AS
CURSOR col_ident IS 
  select col1_name,col2,col3,col4,nullable,'_NM' as s_type
  from table_name 
  where col2 in var_owner 
    and col3 like 'exp%%' 
    and col4 like 'exp2%';

sample_record col_ident%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
OPEN col_ident;
LOOP 
FETCH col_ident INTO sample_record;
  DECLARE
  col_nm VARCHAR2(30);
  tab_nm VARCHAR2(30);
  schema_nm VARCHAR2(30);
  --a1 VARCHAR2(30);
  sqlquery VARCHAR2(400);

  BEGIN

  col_nm := sample_record.col2;
  tab_nm := sample_record.col3;
  schema_nm := sample_record.col1_name;
  IF sample_record.col4 = 'VARCHAR2' THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Who are you ? ');
 sqlquery:= ('select distinct ' +col_nm+ 'from' + schema_nm+'.'+tab_nm + 'where rownum < 1');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Do you know me ');
  END IF;
EXIT WHEN col_ident%NOTFOUND;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sample_record.col1_name||','||sample_record.col3
  ||','||sample_record.col2||','||sample_record.col4||','||
  sample_record.col5||','||sample_record.nullable||','||
  sample_record.s_type);
  END;
END LOOP;
--Close CURSOR col_ident
CLOSE col_ident;
END PROCEDURE2;*
```

Comment: In oracle concatention is done using `||` not `+`. Change line `'select distinct ' +col_nm+ 'from' + schema_nm+'.'+tab_nm + 'where` and replace all the place where `+` is there with `||`

Comment: I've removed incompatible dbms tag. Please don't tag products not involved.

Comment: do what @XING says, besides get rid of paranthesis around that select statement.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks @XING for the resolution. Sometimes it gets a bit messy with all the different tools. The dynamic query is getting stored now but when try to use it to store in a variable I am using this code *sqlquery:=  'select distinct ' ||col_nm|| 'from' || schema_nm||'.'||tab_nm || 'where rownum = 1' ; *  *EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlquery INTO a1;* But I am getting this error *ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
ORA-06512: at "XXX.PROCEDURE2", line 30* Rest of the code is same. Anything which I might need to edit to get over this issues

Comment: @Adee Give some space between from and table name. Change `'from' ||` to `'from  '` it should work then

Comment: @XING - Thanks mate ! Another one of the silly spaces which makes us all go mad. I should be a bit more careful